# How to delete renamed or non-renamed files in Dropzone.js - simple solution

Tags: dropzone.js

I was working on this for a full day until I figured out this simple method that I am sharing with yall.

Answer (score 0):

Use this part to listen to a deletion of a thumbnail:

```
init: function() 
  {
  this.on("removedfile", function(file) 
    { 
    var lot = $(file.previewElement).find('[data-dz-name]').text();
    $.post("image_delete.php",{name: lot});
    });
  }
```

The variable lot gets the name of the image or if you used renameFilename then it gets the new renamed name and with the POST method it is sent to the image_delete.php file that looks like this:

```
<?php
$tobedeleted = "images/".$_POST['name'];
unlink("$tobedeleted");
?>
```

I hope this helps a lot of people who struggled with this problem. 
Happy coding :)